# How do I combine cost and margin formula variables into one?

Tags: excel, vba

I am experiencing an "Application-defined or object-defined error" when attempting to combine my cost variable and multiply it by 1 + marginFormula. How can I solve this issue?

```vb
Sub Expense_Save4()

Dim r As Long, i As Long, serv As Long, qu As Long, cost As Long, marginFormula As Long, TotalFormula As Long
Dim sumValue As Double

' Print Service and Quantity 1-9
For i = 0 To 8
    serv = Sheet1.Range("U12").Offset(i * 6).Value ' Service i+1
    qu = Sheet1.Range("V14").Offset(i * 6).Value ' Quantity i+1
    cost = Sheet1.Range("V16").Offset(i * 6).Value ' Cost i+1
    
    marginFormula = "=INDEX('Products and Services Margins'!$B$2:$AQ$77, MATCH(E" & r + i & ", 'Products and Services Margins'!$A$2:$A$77, 0), MATCH(C" & r + i & ", 'Products and Services Margins'!$A$1:$AQ$1, 0))"
    TotalFormula = "=" & cost & " * (1 + " & marginFormula & ")"

    If Len(serv) > 0 Or Len(qu) > 0 Or Len(cost) > 0 Then
        Sheet1.Range("E" & r + i).Value = serv
        Sheet1.Range("F" & r + i).Value = qu
        Sheet1.Range("G" & r + i).Value = TotalFormula
        Sheet1.Range("H" & r + i).Formula = "=F" & r + i & "*G" & r + i ' Multiply column F and G
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Your `marginFormula` has a leading `=` which should be removed.    In your code where is `r` assigned a value?

Comment: r is assigned as follows ``` With Sheet4
        ' Find the next available row in column A of Sheet2
        r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 ```

Comment: What happened when you cut the `=` from `marginFormula` ?

Comment: The `Formula` variables should be strings. Setting that aside, Are you sure that `r + 1 <> 0`? When I was testing on a blank worksheet, `r + i = 0` was causing the error. Also, are you sure that your conditional can fail? Even on a blank worksheet, `Len(serv) = 4` for whatever reason.